# How can I add a regular user to the sudoers file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

How can I add more users to the "sudoers" file?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just edit the file `/etc/sudoers`.

But you are supped to use `/usr/sbin/visudo` as your editor, since that will to some sanity checks before you exit.

So that would be:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/visudo
```

Here are some links that could be useful:

- [Sudo in a Nutshell](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/intro.html)
- [Sudoers Manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/sudoers.html)

Comment: Then how do I save the file

Comment: Never mind, realized it happened on the exit.

Comment: +1. On some systems, the /etc/sudoers is readonly, and editiion is forced through the visudo command.

Comment: If you have an `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, don't modify the `/etc/sudoers` file. Instead, put the entry in its own file in that directory.

Answer (score 19):

My preferred method is to add them to the `sudo` group (`admin` before Ubuntu 10.04).

In Ubuntu Linux, the `sudo` group can run `sudo` and it is easy to add someone to that group:

```
usermod -a -G sudo username
```

Your mileage may vary with other distros, however, someone thought the group method made more sense than the sudoers file getting itself updatified. Less room for getting it wrong and locking everyone out of being superuser seems to be the reason.

Comment: admin group doesn't exist since at least Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 13):

Just edit your sudoers file

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

and add the username like 'uk' without quotes

```
username ALL = (ALL)ALL
```

Save and exit would give the access.

Comment: Like Johan says, visudo should be used to edit the sudoers file. A borked sudo file can lead to a world of avoidable pain.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visudo

Comment: Why did you add quotes to your example, then?

Answer (score 2):

`visudo` opens the sudoers file and has samples for simple situations.

You may have to add option 'NOPASSWD' if user scripts would use commands/binaries which can be run only with "sudo", e.g.

```
ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It is also possible to specify group instead of user name. So you need not list each and every user, e.g.

```
%users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Beware that NOPASSWD may be a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

In Amazon Linux, there is `/etc/sudoers.d` and inside it is `cloud-init` which contains:

```
ec2-user ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL

# User rules for ec2-user
ec2-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

So all I did was `cp cloud-init vlad`, then edit `vlad` and replace all instances of `ec2-user` with `vlad`. Works fine, and it's obviously as it was intended to be done, rather than editing existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Add to sudo group (Debian / Ubuntu specific step):

```
    $ sudo gpasswd -a <username> sudo

    Adding user <username> to group sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

just by execute this command by a user which has a sudoer permission :

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```