# access as root staying in another user

Tags: linux

i want to install a software in my linux machine staying in another user that i have created .It is asking for root access for some command to be execute during installation process.when I am trying to execute "sudo -s" its showing " is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.".what next will i do.I am in my ubuntu machine.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com)

Comment: or http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a regular user to the sudoers file?](https://superuser.com/questions/39530/how-can-i-add-a-regular-user-to-the-sudoers-file)

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't want to edit `/etc/sudoers` every time you add a new user.  All administrators are given sudo access by default, so you just want to give that user permission to administer the system as outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).  This adds the user to the admin group.

The only time you want to edit `/etc/sudoers` is if you need more finely grained access than administrator or not, such as a user you want to be able to install new software, but not restart the web server, for example.  Also, on the rare occasion you do want to change `/etc/sudoers`, you don't want to just edit it directly.  You need to use the `visudo` command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've messed up your system, or created a new user without modifying the `/etc/sudoers` file.
Login with an account you made when you've installed Ubuntu. Open up a shell, and type: `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`.
Search for these lines:

```
# User privilege specification
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Add an additional entry below that, like `yourusername ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You should log in as root and edit that user into the sudoers file, `/etc/sudoers`. Try `man sudoers` for the full file format documentation, or there should be helpful comments inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

May be not the best solution but it could helps.

Try this as root:

```
# usermod -aG sudo username
```

The change will take effect the next time you log in