# Use sudoedit to add user to sudo group?

Tags: permissions, sudo, openbsd

According to the [OpenBSD FAQ #10](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html):

> If you want to give access to superuser privileges without adding users to the wheel group, use sudo(8).

According to the [OpenBSD man pages on sudo(8)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sudo.8):

> ```
> sudoedit  [-AnS] [-a auth_type] [-C fd] [-c class | -]
>   [-g group name | #gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name | #uid] file ...
> ...
>
>  -A
>     Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the 
>     user's terminal. If the -A (askpass) option is specified
> ```

`-A` is ask for password, and not add a user to the sudoer's group. It appears none of `-AknS` adds a user to the group.

`sudoedit -u <useranme>` just prints help, and does not add the user to the sudoer's group.

How do we add a user to the sudoer's group?

---

A related question is [How can I add a regular user to the sudoers file?](https://superuser.com/q/39530/173513). But it states to edit `/etc/sudoers` directly, which the man pages ***don't*** tell me to do. (Plus, I've learned that the BSDs are different enough from Linux so that we should not blindly follow Linux advice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -A is ask for password, and not add a user to the sudoer's group. It appears none of -AknS adds a user to the group.
>
> How do we add a user to the sudoer's group?

Okay, so the first thing is, **there is no "sudoers group".** (Well, not a default/dedicated one anyway, though it is actually common to configure %wheel or %staff as such a group.)

And if there were, you'd use `usermod` on OpenBSD (or `gpasswd` on Linux) – it's just a regular group modified using regular tools, there is nothing very sudo-ish about it.

The second thing is, **sudoedit is not for modifying groups, it's for editing /etc/sudoers.**

The manual pages tell you not to edit /etc/sudoers *directly*. But editing /etc/sudoers is exactly how you give sudo access to someone (whether a user or a %group).

The only difference is that `sudoedit` performs syntax checks on the edited file, so that you don't accidentally lock out all administrators because of a typo, and makes sure two people aren't editing the same sudoers file at the same time.. Regular `vi /etc/sudoers` wouldn't have such safeguards.

---

So the instructions remain the same. Run `sudoedit` – *just* `sudoedit` – and add your username or chosen group to the sudoers file.

Comment: *"Okay, so the first thing is, there is no "sudoers group"* - that's kind of interesting. When I run, say, *`sudo gmake install`*, I get a message that I'm not in the sudoer's group. (And I did not install `sudo`; its part of the base system).

Comment: OK, so I elevated with `su -` and ran `sudoedit username`. The file appears to be filled with tilde's (`~`). I tried saving it with `X-S X-C`, but it does not appear to have any effect. So I killed the process. This is one of those times I ***really*** despise testing software on multiple platforms....

Comment: X-S X-C has no effect because you're looking at vi, not emacs – the tildes are just what vi shows below the end of the file. Perhaps your $EDITOR did not carry over through 'su'.

Comment: Oh, thanks grawity. I don't use Vi; I use Emacs. I don't even know how to exit from Vi. Maybe that's why I had to kill the process...

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/sudoers` describes which user may execute what using sudo.

But sudoedit is **not** the command to edit the `/etc/sudoers`. sudoedit is used to edit a file as another user.

To edit `/etc/sudoers` you need [visudo(8)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-5.7/man8/visudo.8?query=visudo&sec=8&manpath=OpenBSD-5.7).

If you are using OpenBSD-current, you might consider to use the new [doas(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/doas.1?query=doas) instead of sudo - it is easier to configure.